# Sending/Receiving SMS via Arduino

Tags: sms, embedded, arduino, gsm, gprs

I have a GBoard which contains a SIM900 GSM/GPRS module, a XBEE Shield and an SD Card Slot.

[This is the link of the GBoard product](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/im120411004.html).

I want the Arduino to send and receive SMS on the SIM900 module. To be specific, I want to read SMS mostly, and take some action based on the content of the SMS and then delete it from the SIM card.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I have working to turn an LED on/off via SMS.  You might need to adjust the code for you setup.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8);

// EN: String buffer for the GPRS shield message
// FR: Mémoire tampon de type string pour les messages du shield GPRS 
String SmsStorePos = String("");
String msg = String("");
String snTmp = String("");
String snFull = String("");

// EN: Set to 1 when the next GPRS shield message will contains the SMS message
// FR: Est mis à 1 quand le prochain message du shield GPRS contiendra le contenu du SMS
int SmsContentFlag = 0;

// EN: Pin of the LED to turn ON and OFF depending on the received message
// FR: Pin de la LED a allumer/éteindre en fonction du message reçu
int ledPin = 5;

void setup()
{
  mySerial.begin(19200);               // the GPRS baud rate   
  mySerial.print("\r");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(19200);                 // the GPRS baud rate
  Serial.println("Started!");

  pinMode( ledPin, OUTPUT ); 
  digitalWrite( ledPin, LOW ); 
}

void loop()
{
    char SerialInByte;

    if(Serial.available())
    {
       mySerial.print((unsigned char)Serial.read());
     }  
    else  if(mySerial.available())
    {
        char SerialInByte;
        SerialInByte = (unsigned char)mySerial.read();

        // EN: Relay to Arduino IDE Monitor
        // FR: Relayer l'information vers le moniteur Serie Arduino
        Serial.print( SerialInByte );

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // EN: Program also listen to the GPRS shield message.
        // FR: Le programme écoute également les messages issus du GPRS Shield.
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------

        // EN: If the message ends with <CR> then process the message
        // FR: Si le message se termine par un <CR> alors traiter le message 
        if( SerialInByte == 13 ){
          // EN: Store the char into the message buffer
          // FR: Stocké le caractère dans le buffer de message
          ProcessGprsMsg();
         }
         if( SerialInByte == 10 ){
            // EN: Skip Line feed
            // FR: Ignorer les Line Feed 
         }
         else {
           // EN: store the current character in the message string buffer
           // FR: stocker le caractère dans la mémoire tampon réservé au message
           msg += String(SerialInByte);
         }
     }   
}

// EN: Make action based on the content of the SMS. 
//     Notice than SMS content is the result of the processing of several GPRS shield messages.
// FR: Execute une action sur base du contenu d'un SMS.
//     Notez que le contenu du SMS est le résultat du traitement de plusieurs messages du shield GPRS.
void ProcessSms( String sms ){
  sms.toLowerCase();
  Serial.print( "ProcessSms for [" );
  Serial.print( sms );
  Serial.println( "]" );

  if( sms.indexOf("on") >= 0 ){
    digitalWrite( ledPin, HIGH );
    Serial.println( "LED IS ON" );
    return;
  }
  if( sms.indexOf("off") >= 0 ){
    digitalWrite( ledPin, LOW );
    Serial.println( "LED IS OFF" );
    return;
  } else {
    mySerial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    //Because we want to send the SMS in text mode
    delay(1000);
    mySerial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    mySerial.print(snFull);
    mySerial.print("\"\r");
    delay(1000);
    mySerial.print("Unknown Command: ");
    mySerial.print(sms);
    mySerial.print("\r");
    delay(1000);
    mySerial.write(0x1A);  //Equivalent to sending Ctrl+Z     
    return;
  }
}
// EN: Request Text Mode for SMS messaging
// FR: Demande d'utiliser le mode Text pour la gestion des messages
void GprsTextModeSMS(){
  mySerial.println( "AT+CMGF=1" );
}

void GprsReadSmsStore( String SmsStorePos ){
  // Serial.print( "GprsReadSmsStore for storePos " );
  // Serial.println( SmsStorePos ); 
  mySerial.print( "AT+CMGR=" );
  mySerial.println( SmsStorePos );
}

// EN: Clear the GPRS shield message buffer
// FR: efface le contenu de la mémoire tampon des messages du GPRS shield.
void ClearGprsMsg(){
  msg = "";
}

// EN: interpret the GPRS shield message and act appropiately
// FR: interprete le message du GPRS shield et agit en conséquence
void ProcessGprsMsg() {
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print( "GPRS Message: [" );
  Serial.print( msg );
  Serial.println( "]" );

  if( msg.indexOf( "Call Ready" ) >= 0 ){
     Serial.println( "*** GPRS Shield registered on Mobile Network ***" );
     GprsTextModeSMS();
  }

  // EN: unsolicited message received when getting a SMS message
  // FR: Message non sollicité quand un SMS arrive
  if( msg.indexOf( "+CMTI" ) >= 0 ){
     Serial.println( "*** SMS Received ***" );
     // EN: Look for the coma in the full message (+CMTI: "SM",6)
     //     In the sample, the SMS is stored at position 6
     // FR: Rechercher la position de la virgule dans le message complet (+CMTI: "SM",6) 
     //     Dans l'exemple, le SMS est stocké à la position 6
     int iPos = msg.indexOf( "," );
     SmsStorePos = msg.substring( iPos+1 );
     Serial.print( "SMS stored at " );
     Serial.println( SmsStorePos );

     // EN: Ask to read the SMS store
     // FR: Demande de lecture du stockage SMS
     GprsReadSmsStore( SmsStorePos );
  }

  // EN: SMS store readed through UART (result of GprsReadSmsStore request)  
  // FR: Lecture du stockage SMS via l'UART (résultat de la requete GprsReadSmsStore)
  if( msg.indexOf( "+CMGR:" ) >= 0 ){
    // get number of sender
    int snPos = msg.indexOf("+1");
    Serial.print("SMS From: ");
    snTmp = msg.substring(snPos+1);
    snFull = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
      snFull += snTmp[i];    
    }
    Serial.println(snFull);

    // EN: Next message will contains the BODY of SMS
    // FR: Le prochain message contiendra le contenu du SMS
    SmsContentFlag = 1;
    // EN: Following lines are essentiel to not clear the flag!
    // FR: Les ligne suivantes sont essentielle pour ne pas effacer le flag!
    ClearGprsMsg();
    return;
  }

  // EN: +CMGR message just before indicate that the following GRPS Shield message 
  //     (this message) will contains the SMS body
  // FR: le message +CMGR précédent indiquait que le message suivant du Shield GPRS 
  //     (ce message) contient le corps du SMS 
  if( SmsContentFlag == 1 ){
    Serial.println( "*** SMS MESSAGE CONTENT ***" );
    Serial.println( msg );
    Serial.println( "*** END OF SMS MESSAGE ***" );
    ProcessSms( msg );
    delSMS();
  }

  ClearGprsMsg();
  // EN: Always clear the flag
  // FR: Toujours mettre le flag à 0
  SmsContentFlag = 0; 
}
void delSMS() {
  mySerial.print("AT+CMGD=");
  mySerial.println(SmsStorePos);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Sir :) But I completed my project without the GSM Module feature. :(

Comment: Well done getting this code out there =) Just like what i wrote last night!

Answer (score 1):

If someone don't want to use the shield you can also use this  [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ram.mere.DoDuino) !

and here is the [tutorial] (https://sites.google.com/site/blueact0/sms-action)!

Update :
You can now use  BlueAct also with Serial ( not only bluetooth ) but your device should support OTG Cable :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi I suggest you follow the example in the [gsmshield](https://github.com/jgarland79/GSM_Shield/blob/master/GSM_Shield.cpp#L1506) library linked to from GBoard Usefull Links.

Comment: That code seems to have some error associated with the header files. Could you please provide some alternative code ?